# A very small text I tried to write, could you correct it?

Tags: выбор-слова

I've been learning Russian for two weeks and I tried to write a small text in order to practice. Could you please correct it? Thanks in advance! Here it is:

> Я живу с моей семьёй в малом городком в Италии, где я уродился, хотя
> мои родители - из Польши; поэтому я говорю также по-польски кроме
> итальянского. Наш дом имеет кухню, гостиную, банную комнату и наконец
> пару спален. Честно говоря, несмотря на то, что у меня не большой
> семьй, однако чувствую иногда, словно наш дом не был такой
> вместителен.

I have some questions as well: 1) Could you omit "комната" in the words "банная комната" and "гостиная комната". Which version is the more used? 2) Is there any difference between "несмотря на" and "хотя"? I used the former in order not to repeat the latter, but I don't know if there's any nuance.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Karol! Unfortunately, we don't correct texts on this site as a rule. However, there's a site called Journaly.com where you can post your texts and natives will offer corrections *within* your text, which is super cool. See you there!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it. I'll be using journaly.com, thanks!

Comment: "уродился" is not used to mark people's place of birth. Just "родился" should be used in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> Could you omit "комната" in the words "<strike>банная</strike> ванная комната" and "гостиная комната".

Yes, you can.

> Which version is the more used?

The one without the word *комната*. More often than not, they are just *ванная* and *гостиная*.

The word *банный* usually applies specifically to Russian steam bath and not bath in general, although there are a couple of set phrases like *банный день, банный пункт* etc. where *банный* does mean "related to personal hygiene".

> Is there any difference between "несмотря на" and "хотя"?

*Несмотря на* means "despite", *хотя* means "though".

This particular sentence we can write both ways:

> Честно говоря, несмотря на то, что семья у меня небольшая, мне иногда кажется, что наш дом не такой уж и вместительный.
>
> Честно говоря, хотя семья у меня и небольшая, мне иногда кажется, что наш дом не такой уж и вместительный.

Same as in English, you can use both "despite the fact my family is not large" and "even though my family is not large".

Comment: Thank you very much!